# Hello World - Backbone + Firebase + Backfire

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a simple hello world with backbone and firebase(using backfire). The code is working to insert data to firebase, but when I try to get data and fill the template, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: firstName is not defined". On debug I can see the object with the data but I don't know how to provide the template with this object.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var registerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    });

    var registerColletion = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
        model:registerModel,
        firebase: new Firebase("https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/")
    });

    var registerView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#myTest"),
        itemTemplate: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
        events: {
            "click #btnSave": "saveToFirebase"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(registerList, 'add', this.render);
        },
        render: function(){
            $('#divContent').html(this.itemTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        },
        saveToFirebase: function () {
            registerList.add({firstName: $("#txtFirstName").val(), lastName: $("#txtLastName").val()});
        }
    });

    var registerList = new registerColletion;
    var app = new registerView({model:registerList});
});
```

The exact point of the exception is on render function:

```
render: function(){
            $('#divContent').html(this.itemTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        },
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view">
        <p>
            <%- firstName %> <%- lastName %>
        </p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me? I think I'm missing something (probably obvious) but I can't see it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `registerView` you're telling it that the underlying model is a `registerList` (not a `registerModel`)

```
var app = new registerView({model:registerList});
```

Therefore, when the `render` function is called, it's looking for the `firstName` property of a `registerList`, and that property doesn't exist.

Seems like you've got Models and Collections mixed up

Comment: Hi Stephen! I'm using registerList because it is an instance of registerColletion that has a model on it. If I use registerModel, when the application render, the function toJSON is not available. 'this.model' points to a function on backbone using registerModel: "function (){return r.apply(this,arguments)} backbone.js:1566". Any guess? Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to set up one view for the collection and a separate view for the model. The collection view can just create and render model views. In the model view you can use `this.model.toJSON` to create the template parameters.